# Why can't javac compiler find javafx.collections but I'm using it?

Tags: java, javafx, javac

Here's the relevant portion of my code

```
package ReadWriteDisplayTriangles;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.collections;

class TrianglePane extends Pane{

    private RecordTable recordTable;

    //other code

    public void setToRecordTable() {
        ObservableList<Node> list = getChildren();
        int size = list.size();
        recordTable.setNewRecordArray(size);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(Debug.isDebug5() == true) {System.out.println("Observable list " + i + " is " + list.get(i)); }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output from javac -verbose

```
[search path for class files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\resources.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\rt.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\jsse.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\jce.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\charsets.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\jfr.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\classes,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-32.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar,C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar,.]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar(javafx/scene/layout/Pane.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar(javafx/scene/paint/Color.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar(javafx/scene/shape/Polygon.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar(javafx/event/ActionEvent.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar(javafx/event/EventHandler.class)]]
TrianglePane.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import javafx.collections;
             ^
  symbol:   class collections
  location: package javafx
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar(javafx/scene/layout/Region.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar(javafx/scene/Parent.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar(javafx/scene/Node.class)]]
```

I have a few questions.

1. TrianglePane extends Pane. In the documentation for [javafx.scene.layout.Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html), it lists as a method getChildren() which returns an ObservableList. Since the class it extends has a method that returns an observable list, why do I have to import javafx.collections at all?
2. getChildren().add(...) works in other parts of this same code, so it must have access to Observable Lists somehow, right?
3. Why is javafx.collections not importing? I can import everything else from javafx.
4. What can I do to fix my compiler, libraries, or whatever to be able to utilize a reference for this observable list?

I'm using jdk1.8.0_241

Thanks for any input, I'm new to coding and having a blast.

Comment: unrelated: java naming conventions please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To import a complete package, you need to use `*`:

```
import javafx.collections.*;
```

Alternatively, import the class by its name:

```
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
```